# ReactTestUtils findRenderedComponentWithType throwing error not detecting by chai?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, reactjs-testutils

Im using findRenderedComponentWithType to make sure there is a error, and Im using chai's assert.throws, but it is not working.

---

first of all:

TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType documentation:

`expects there to be one result and returns that one result, or throws exception if there is any other number of matches besides one.`

---

When I use the function, Im getting an error (as expected and correct).
However I cant seems to assert it properly with chai:
I tried `assert.throws(TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(element, component),  /(Error)/)`. But it is saying the test failed, even though I'm getting an error:

```
 Error: Did not find exactly one match for componentType:function (props, context, updater) {
 [...]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the signature of throws, it expects a function, not an error/object (which is the result of `findRenderedComponentWithType`. 
http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_throws

So you will want to do something like

```
cons fn = () => TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(element, component)
assert.throws(fn)
```

Comment: first of all it works thanks. I actually read that before too, but I didn't realize method and function is different by definition, but then I still dont really see how this made a diff. Doesnt chai just run whatever in the first parameter then check what it output? does it have something to do with callback?

Comment: Your initial implementation wasn't passing in a function (or method).  It has do with the order things are executed in.  The `TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(element, component)` gets executed first and returns either a Component object or throws an error.  So really you are passing in one of those types.

Think of how it might be implemented.  It takes a function, then wraps it in a try/catch block THEN executes it.  Whereas you were executing it THEN behind the scenes it was getting wrapped, but by then it is too late; the error has been thrown

Comment: As a side note, you might want to check out https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme.  I found the ReactTestUtils lib to be a bit of a pain to work with (especially those method names) so ended up writing my own before Enzyme became available.

Comment: oh yeah, wow that's embarassing, thanks. I've been seeing people talking about enzyme too, I'll take a look thanks!